# Is it possible to get the "Informed" badge in Code Review meta?

Tags: support, meta, badges

In fact, for me it seems impossible. Everytime I open [Meta's tour page](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/tour) to read the entire tour page to get the "Informed" badge I'm redirected to [the main site's tour page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: A long time ago, I joked that badges like these taught a lesson to people who try to earn every last badge. Then Jeff [said I was actually right](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71737/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This applies to all sites, not just CR.  I don't know exactly why this is done, but I do know that [there are still unobtainable badges listed on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121922/remove-impossible-badges-from-per-site-metas).

Comment: you're right! I've not even noticed. thanks for the answer. it seems only be possible to get the badge on the [dedicated meta page](http://meta.stackexchange.com).